# Predicting a cyclic target

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I'm familiar with using trigonometric functions to transform cyclic variables for use as *features* in training a model (most commonly hour of the day or month of the year); I'm now trying to figure out the best way of doing this for using these types of variables as the *target* for my model. (Imagine a model predicting the month when a particular event is most likely to occur, for instance). Neither using a strictly-increasing representation (so that January, 2018 is close to December, 2017 but very far from January, 2017) nor treating the month as a categorical variable is ideal, but the trigonometric encoding done for features requires both `sin` and `cos` parts to have a unique representation of each month, so using one of the two isn't a workable approach either.  Is there a better option that I'm missing?

Comment: You can still do the sin/cos trick, but use a bivariate model.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant terminology is "multi-output" or "multi-target" regression/classification.  A [survey article from a few years ago](http://oa.upm.es/40804/1/INVE_MEM_2015_204213.pdf) has some good discussion. This functionality is implemented in many packages (for instance, in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput) (where it extends the functionality of other regressors, rather than being an independent implementation) and in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultivariateRandomForest/MultivariateRandomForest.pdf).

Comment: Keras‘ functional API also provides a good way to model multi-targets. See this post for a minimal example: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64350/71442