# Neural Network for Multiple Dependent Outputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, multi-output

I have a dataset with approx 6 input features and 5 output values to be predicted. I am trying to understand what kind of neural network would be most suitable to assign probability across multiple dependent outputs, with the motivation to maximise the value of a single feature.

For example, suppose the inputs are:

```
company size
number of employees
turnover
average salary
country
years of operation
```

And the outputs to be predicted are:

```
% budget allocated to marketing
% budget allocated to sales
% budget allocated to R&D
% budget allocated to training
% budget allocated to shareholders
```

The training dataset also contains the column:

```
profit
```

Which is what I want to optimise against (i.e. the primary motivation of the model).

For a given set of inputs (company size, number of employees, turnover, average salary, country, years of operation), I want to be able to predict values for the 5 outputs which are most likely to achieve the highest 'profit'. The sum of the 5 outputs must equal 100%.

In other words, there is a finite budget to be allocated, and I want to create a model to predict the best budget allocation to maximise profit.

What neural network would be most suitable for this purpose? I have looked into [multi-output regression](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39116/neural-network-for-multiple-integer-output), however I imagine this would assign **independent** probabilities for each of the 5 outputs (i.e. they won't add up to 100%).

Is it possible for probability to instead be assined to each output **dependent** of the other outputs (i.e. so they add up to 100%)? If so, is there a name for this type of approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, at the end of a neural network you could find a **Softmax** layer, which outputs probabilities, so they add up to 1. It seems exactly what you're looking for. Please find more information about softmax function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) or [here](https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-the-softmax-function-in-minutes-f3a59641e86d).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I need :) In my example, would 'profit' be an input, an output, or neither? I don't believe it's an input, as profit won't be available to input into the model, and I don't believe it's an output, as am not trying to predict profit for a given set of inputs. Rather I am trying to predict the outputs that are most likely to generate the highest profit (based on training data examples). Is it possible to therefore specify a 'motivation' variable which the model strives to maximise? Apologies if I've overlooked something basic, I'm quite new to machine learning :)

Comment: It's an interesting question :). Could you please post it separately to not confuse users with the softmax issue ?